# Multiple call of char[] returning function for immediately fprint

Tags: c, function, char, printf, return-value

I look for a comfortable way of converting a custom type variable to char[] (string) for the purpose of immediate fprinting. Here is what I intend to do, yet still flawed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * toStr (int);

void main (void) {
   printf("%s , %s , %s \n", toStr(1), toStr(2), toStr(3));
}

char * toStr (int z) {

    static char oS[100];
    sprintf(oS, "%d", z);
    printf("Will return: %s\n", oS);
    return oS;
}
```

This will display

```
Will return: 3
Will return: 2
Will return: 1
1 , 1 , 1
```

I see what the problem is here, printf seems to print the content of static char oS once for all three calls in its parameterlist. It does not evaluate each call exactely when it is needed in the format string. But i need the static (as one possible way) to make the content of oS available outside of toStr.
I feel like I am almost there, of corse I want the output

```
1 , 2 , 3
```

on screen. Is there a possiblility to get what I want, without having to mallocate and free every part or storing each return of toStr in a sepearate variable just to fprint them aftwerwards? Isn't it possible to fprint the return values of the same function multiple times in one call?

Comment: You should realize that when you call printf, it is passed four parameters, and three of them are identical. The first is the format string `"%s , %s , %s \n"` and the other three are each set to the address of the static character array `oS` -- because that's what `toStr()` returns every time you call it.

Answer (score 1):

Local `static` variables are *shared* between all invocations of the function. That means all calls will use the same buffer and return the same pointer to the same string.

And since the evaluation order of arguments is not specified (I don't remember if it's implementation defined, undefined, or just simply not specified), then you don't know which will be the last call (which will be the call the decides which the contents of the array will have).

The only thing you *do* know is that *all* arguments must be evaluated *before* the actual call to the function is made. Arguments and expressions are not evaluated lazily.

Answer (score 1):

The order of evaluation of function arguments is [*unspecified*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior). So `printf` doesn't necessarily evaluate it in any order you desire/expect.

As you debug prints show, `toStr` does write multiple value to `oS`. But *all* arguments of `printf` will be evaluated before the function call is made.
So the whatever the value written as will be value written by printf for all 3 arguments since the function `toStr` returns the pointer to the *same* object (`oS` in `toStr`).

Note that function-local `static` variables are error prone as it's not thread-safe.

> But i need the static (as one possible way) to make the content of oS available outside of toStr.

It's not possible to achieve what you want in your current way. You can either ask `toStr` to allocate memory each time (save it in the caller and free it after use).
Or pass the buffer you to write to each time:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *toStr(char *, size_t, int);

int main (void)
{
    char s1[256];
    char s2[256];
    char s3[256];
    /* could also use s[3][256]; instead 3 separate vars */

    printf("%s , %s , %s\n", toStr(s1, sizeof s1, 1), toStr(s2, sizeof s2, 2), toStr(s3, sizeof s3, 3));
}

char *toStr(char *oS, size_t len, int z)
{
    snprintf(oS, len, "%d", z);
    printf("Will return: %s\n", oS);
    return oS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After 3 calls to the function printf prarameters point to the same `static` buffer - and this buffer contains (which obvious only the one information.

You can check the evaluation order of your implementation without `printf`s inside the function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *foo(const int i)
{
    static char c[200] = {0,};

    sprintf(&c[strlen(c)], "i = %d ", i);
    return c;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%s %s %s\n", foo(1), foo(2), foo(3));
    return 0;
}
```